# Why can't I equip new suits in Batman: Arkham City?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I've been playing Batman: Arkham City for a while and I have just bought some new suits, but I can't equip them. The only suit I can equip is the Batman Inc. suit. I have even tried the cheat codes, and it still won't let me.

When I try to download it again, there is an option for "wear now", but I can't select it.

I've completed 47% and the main story. Do I need to complete more?

Comment: What system is this on? PC, PS3, 360 or Wii U?

Answer (score 8):

If memory serves me right, **you cannot normally change Batman's costume until you have beaten the story mode at least once**. You should be able to select your costume in *Riddler's challenge missions*, though. Once you've beaten the game once, you should be able to select your costume, in either *Story Mode* or *Story Mode+* .

I am not aware of any cheats to change costumes on your first playthrough, but I have not been looking much. [This GameFAQs question](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/981375-batman-arkham-city/answers/297240-how-do-u-change-your-costume-in-the-campain) has one promising looking cheat, but I do not know if it's one that you've already tried or if it works on your system. (Because I don't know what system you are playing on.)

> To wear one of the skins for your first playthrough **select your game save** then press Left, Left, Down, Down, Left, Left, Right, Up, Up, Down. Then begin your game. You can then pick from any of the skins you have downloaded for Batman.

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

It’s in main menu when selecting your game save, instead of selecting continue story select Showcase, and will give you skin options for your suit and batmobile, whilst also give you the option to change character, and select a different vehicle